# Return 2d array in function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to return a 2d array but it gives me the errors:

could not convert brace-enclosed initializer list to int
cannot convert 'int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)terrainSize) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'int*' in return

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

int* terrainGenerator(int terrainSize){
    int tArray[terrainSize][terrainSize];
    tArray[0][0] = {1,1};
    return tArray;
}


int main(){
    terrainGenerator(1);
}
```

Comment: Your coordinates are 2 dimensions, but each value of the array is a single int. What are you trying to do? If you want to have a tuple of values for each array element, you need a different data structure.

Comment: You can not return pointer to allocated on stack variables

Comment: Easier for you: Get a pointer from the calling function, that also solves the problem with memory leaks if you create the array in one function and delete it in another (or not, when you forget it).

Comment: You cannot return c-style arrays from functions in C or C++. You need a different approach.